# Aviso de confirmação

Tags: asp.net

Estou em um projeto em ASP.NET e entrei em uma situação em que precisa de um aviso para um botão.

Este botão excluía o arquivo, mas sem nenhum tipo de confirmação e no caso de clicar sem querer teria o seu arquivo deletado.

E então queria saber como que posso colocar um aviso do tipo: 'Deseja realmente excluir?' e esperar a confirmação do OK para excluir ou então um modo de Cancelar a ação.

Em algumas pesquisas consegui a resposta que mandei abaixo que no meu caso serve, mas teria alguma outra forma sem usar javascript?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a ajuda for muito simples ainda é possível fazer nos comentários.

Comment: @Maniero, não encontrei nada no site sobre esse assunto e apenas em outros sites que consegui a resposta, achei talvez seria bom compartilhar.

Comment: @PedroBelino E fez bem, basta melhorar a pergunta para algo que mais pessoas pudessem responder. Veja como elaborar um [mcve], por exemplo, e busque detalhar melhor o problema. Podemos também observar que a pergunta é um tanto tendenciosa, dado que fez a pergunta sobre ASP.NET e respondeu utilizando JavaScript. Se fizer essa busca em JS, achará inúmeras duplicatas. Veja em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+confirm

Comment: @Maniero entendi, acha que melhorou? é que minha aplicação está em asp.net e pesquisando por asp não achei anda, apesar de ter usado js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como descrito na pergunta, em algumas pesquisas, consegui resolver apenas usando js dentro da minha aplicação mesmo sendo em asp.net.

Uma maneira bem simples foi colocar o OnClientClick no próprio botão e fazer toda essa validação e após isso ele faz o OnCommand.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="exclr" OnClientClick="return confirm('Deseja realmente excluir?');" Text="Excluir" OnCommand="exclr_Command"/>
```